# Parsing Custom Tags with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I am trying to do pretty much the same thing as here, but in ruby:

[[Parsing Custom Tags with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201778/parsing-custom-tags-with-php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201778/parsing-custom-tags-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/), as it is faster than hpricot and still has an active maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot).  It's an easy to use HTML parser.