# Replace custom html tag with hyperlink using php

Tags: php, html, replace, html-parsing, custom-tag

I have a custom html tag in my apps that looks like this:

```
<wiki href="articletitle">Text</wiki>`
```

and want to replace it with this:

```
<a href="http://myapps/page/articletitle">Text</a>
```

How I can do that in PHP?

Comment: Whose code is creating those custom tags?

Comment: I have reopened this question because the duplicate makes no attempt to resolve the question asked.  This is a duplicate used to tell a user that their question is not welcome.  This canonical provides an unenjoyable UX for researchers seeking a clear resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Ruel is right, DOM parsing is the correct way to approach it. As an exercise in regex, however, something like this should work:

```
<?php
$string = '<wiki href="articletitle">Text</wiki>';
$pattern = '/<wiki href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/wiki>/i';
$replacement = '<a href="http://myapps/page/$1">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm [trying to do something very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944091/parse-cfml-tags-in-php).  I recommend avoiding regEx like the plague.  It's never as easy as it seems and those corner cases will cause nightmares.

Right now I'm leaning towards the [Custom Tags](http://buggedcom.co.uk/projects/CustomTags.zip) library [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220022/creating-custom-html-tags-for-cms/3220078#3220078).  One of the best features is support for buried or nested tags like the code block below:

```
<ct:upper type="all">
    This text is transformed by the custom tag.<br />
    Using the default example all the characters should be made into uppercase characters.<br />
    Try changing the type attribute to 'ucwords' or 'ucfirst'.<br />
    <br />
    <ct:lower>
        <strong>ct:lower</strong><br />
        THIS IS LOWERCASE TEXT TRANSFORMED BY THE ct:lower CUSTOM TAG even though it's inside the ct:upper tag.<br />
        <BR />
    </ct:lower>
</ct:upper>
```

I highly recommend downloading the zip file and looking through the examples it contains.

Comment: Php has a preloaded library that will suffice, no need to load an extra one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex when a legitimate parser can do the job more reliably.

Since your document contains invalid markup, you will need to silence the parser's discontent before the html is loaded.

I prefer to use DOMDocument and its declarative/self-explanatory methods.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FKcle))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <wiki href="articletitle">Text</wiki>
</div>
HTML;
$appPath = 'http://myapps/page/';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('wiki') as $wiki) {
    $a = $dom->createElement('a');
    $a->setAttribute('href', $appPath . $wiki->getAttribute('href'));
    $a->nodeValue = $wiki->nodeValue;
    $wiki->parentNode->replaceChild($a, $wiki);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://myapps/page/articletitle">Text</a>
</div>
```