# Custom HTML Tags in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, custom-tags

When I was playing around with Joomla! source code, I saw such as code (or similar to this one, I am not pretty sure since it was a while back then):

```
<juc:place name="module" some-other-attributes/>
```

I am not telling it was exactly like the one above but I was surprised actually when I saw Asp.NET-like custom tags:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLabel" runat="server"/>
```

I am now wondering how to accomplish same thing or similar in PHP like they did in Asp.NET. Is there any library for framework for this or so forth?

Do I need to write a parser which parses  my php code and searches for such tags and replaces them with what's corresponding like Asp.NET replaces `<asp:Label/>` with `<span/>`

**My personal preference:**

I like what Asp.NET did by separating code-behind from design-view or html from c# code. And using asp.net's server-side controls enable developer to access html control from code-behind easily. It sounds like separation of concerns and I am wondering if there is any project or way which has done same thing already?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a fan of Asp.NET from what I talked with others but couldn't you achieve something similar with a templating engine? First thing that comes to mind is Smarty, which I use for quite some time now, very reliable and easy to hack.

Comment: PHP is an interpreting language which means it executes line by line code while itself gets configured into apache or IIS environment and then executes any file that ends PHP. Which means everything executes at server side, while .net uses Just in time compiler, which saves the syntaxes and executes at a later stage. This would be possible, but something fundementally you need to change PHP. i.e. make it like JIT compiler...!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Custom Tags with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201778/parsing-custom-tags-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an approach, where presentation layer is stored separately from execution logic (for instance, a templating engine), then it is quite easy to create a parser which looks for specific code in HTML and replaces it with shomething else. You could make your own "SMARTY" language.

However, if your code is just "executable PHP" with no layer separation, you can't do such replacements (as it is directly executed by PHP scripting engine). By "executable php" I mean something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php echo "Hello world"?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hit about template engines

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use an MVC framework (Zend Framework, Codeigniter or similar) which does a lot of separation of concerns for you.

As suggested, SMARTY is a template engine that does pretty much what you're after, but that's really only one part of the puzzle.  Abstracting your data access layer is also a good idea.

You can also enable short tags on your server config, then you can even tidy up your presentation code with something like...

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= "Hello, world!" ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dont confuse `<?` with `<?=` is not short tag its alternative syntax basically it means `<?php echo`, and is supported on php5 and above no need to enable it

Comment: Gee, really?  I understand your concern.  However, what if they're wanting to also use more "template style" markup like <? foreach($var as $k => $v) : ?>

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You can then run something like...

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file(fileToParse.html');
foreach($html->find('tagToFind') as $element){
    $element->tag='span';
}
```

That should work.

You may want to have a look at [Creating custom html tags for cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220022/creating-custom-html-tags-for-cms)